# Webpack resolve externals of imported library

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, webpack-4

I'm trying to create a library with webpack. My main goal is mostly to publish the ES6 module files so that my client applications and import and tree shake the library. (It is meant to be a library of icons, so that users can just bundle the ones they use in their app).

I have the library building the umd module to dist and I've set the `module` field in the package.json to the src directory file that is exporting all of my icons.

Each icon is a React component. I've imported React and PropTypes to create each one and set them to be externals in the webpack config, however I don't think that matters in this use case because...

I made a test application that npm linked my library and imported one of my icon components from my module. It's definitely going to the source files but my webpack here in my application cannot resolve `react` and `prop-types` in those modules. It complains for each in every component.

e.g:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/code/svg-icons/src/components'
@ ../svg-icons/src/components/AlertIcon.js
@ ../svg-icons/src/index.js
@ ./src/index.js
```

I suppose this makes sense, as the AlertIcon module from my library doesn't have a node_module directory to find `react`.

How do I have other applications provide `react`, `prop-types`, and whatever else I want to import in my library's source modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `svg-icons` package, you only need to run it through Babel, to transpile it to ES5, that's it.

Your application that depends on `svg-icons` is the one that will be built with `webpack`, and it will take care of bundling the imported icons into your app bundle.

There is a great FREE course on the subject by [Kent C. Dodds on egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-introduction-to-how-to-write-an-open-source-javascript-library). It will clear everything on the subject for you.

Comment: Well my use case is a bit more specific I think? My intended 'users' are apps that are being babel'ed then webpack'ed already. I was hoping they would install my module and import it much like they do their own src/ modules. Put another way *they* would babel and pack these icons, and tree shake out the import statements they use. Is this what Kent is talking about?

Comment: 3rd party packages (and you package WILL BE a 3rd party package because it will be installed in node_modules) are almost never included in babel processing, so it's your job to publish ES5 code. However, they are processed with webpack and will be bundled via `import/require`. Forcing developers to transpile your package adds a lot of problems, especially when you are not in control of the build process (like with most CRA apps). And treeshaking has nothing to do with it. If developers are importing your icons one by one, they will only include those icons in their build.